# aapt.exe exited with error code 1 msb6006

Tags: android, xamarin

Hi I am new to xamarin My application worked fine on xamarin (old version) then I installed new version ( Blue: I think 4 or 3.4 I cannot find the version information of the new or Old; so I am using colors: old= mix of green violet white yellow; new=blue) My application I created in old xamarin ran fine on the new version. then I tried to change the name of my old application and for this I created a new application on new Xamarin and gave the name I want; then I copied code and resources from my old application to the new application; when i build I get the error aapt.exe existed with error code 1(MSB6006) `Aapt JavaPlatformJarPath="$(JavaPlatformJarPath)" ManifestFile="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)\AndroidManifest.xml" PackageName="$(_AndroidPackage)" ResourceDirectory="$(MonoAndroidResDirIntermediate)" JavaDesignerOutputDirectory="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)" ResourceOutputFile="$(ResgenTemporaryDirectory)\resources.apk" ExtraPackages="$(AaptExtraPackages)" AdditionalResourceDirectories="$(LibraryResourceDirectories)" LibraryProjectJarsWildcard="$(IntermediateOutputPath)**library_projects***.jar" ExtraArgs="$(AndroidResgenExtraArgs)" ToolPath="$(AaptToolPath)" ToolExe="$(AaptToolExe)" AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths="@(_AdditionalAndroidResourcePaths)"

`